# How to bold parts of a run

Tags: vba, ms-word, openxml

I want to bold certain parts of a Run in OpenXML for Word documents using visual basic. I can bold the whole thing, or none of it, but not certain parts. If I can't do this, (it seems like I can't), what alternatives can I try?

Comment: what is `a Run` ?

Comment: please post an example of the text, how it is highlighted, and how you would like it to be highlighted  .... picture would be great

Comment: @jsotola:  A *run* (`w:r`) in OOXML is a stretch of text with common properties, such as bold.

Comment: Of course you can apply a bold character property to a run in OOXML, but this is not a code-writing service.   Update your question with real code and ask a concrete question, or it'll be closed as too broad.

Comment: @kjhughes I've almost done it so I'll post my answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to bold parts of a Run. Instead, one must take the parent of the Run in question (using the .Parent feature), and append multiple runs to the Parent. Or this is what I did. To bold a particular run, I used

```
                                    Dim RunProperties = New RunProperties()
                                    Dim Bold = New Bold()
                                    Bold.Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(True)
                                    RunProperties.AppendChild(Bold)
                                    thisrun.PrependChild(RunProperties)
```

And later, `thispara.AppendChild(thisrun)`.